# web service call causing my app to crash

Tags: android, web-services, titanium, onerror

Hi all I am trying to integrate a webservice in Titanium but when I press the button to call it my log is terminated and my app freezes. I am getting no error messages. Below is my code:

```
        Post_array.push({
            variable1:value1,
            variable2:value2
            variable3:value3
        });



    var AddJobURL="http:/NUMBERS/MytestURL";
    var AddJobxhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    AddJobxhr.onload=function(){
        console.log("Response text ----------------------"+ this.responseText);
        var doc= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    };

    AddJobxhr.onerror=function(e){
        alert(e.error);
    };

    AddJobxhr.open('POST', AddJobURL);
    AddJobxhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    AddJobxhr.send(Post_array);
```

**EDIT:** I've realised the problem. My issue is my Post_array. What I am currently doing is pushing 4 items to an array on a button click and then pushing an additional 4 items on a second different button click and then posting this array but the array at his point is [object Object],[object Object] I think this is my issue? Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

The format of the sending data is not correct here I guess.

Below is the format in which you need to send the data:

```
AddJobxhr.send({
  variable1: "value1",
  variable2: "value2" 
});
```

Where as **Post_array** is an array and not in the above format.

You should do something like:

```
var Post_array = {};

Post_array = $.extend(Post_array, {
  "variable1": "value1",
  "variable2": "value2",
  "variable3": "value3"
});

Post_array = $.extend(Post_array, {
  "variable4": "value4",
  "variable5": "value5",
  "variable6": "value6"
});

AddJobxhr.send(Post_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I am using titanium classic I don't think I can utilise extend as you suggested. With regard ti the quotation marks, some of my variables are ints and some are strings, should they all still have the quotes wrapped around?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do:

```
var Post_array = {};

// Doesn't have to be in quotes it's just the value you assign, strings are in quotes 
// where as integers are not. Let us assume that value1, valu2 and value3 are the
// variable and they can hold anything;

Post_array["variable1"] = value1; 
Post_array["variable2"] = value2; 
Post_array["variable3"] = value3; 

Post_array["variable4"] = value4; 
Post_array["variable5"] = value5; 
Post_array["variable6"] = value6;

AddJobxhr.send(Post_array);
```